# Chrome popup loading and printing after window.load

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, popup, font-face

I have a popup and I need to call print function after window.load event.
I've used this syntax:

```
var popup = window.open(.....);
$(popup).load(function() 
{
popup.print();

});
```

everything is ok in FF but in Chrome print function calls before web font loads completely.
What's the problem?

Comment: Are the web fonts loaded asynchronously maybe …?

Comment: I'm loadin them like this :
@font-face {
  font-family: 'bbc';
 
  src: url("../fonts/bbc-nassim-regular.eot");
 
  src: local("☺"),
  url("../fonts/bbc-nassim-regular.ttf") format("opentype"),
    url("../fonts/bbc-nassim-regular.woff") format("woff"),
    url("../fonts/bbc-nassim-regular.otf") format("opentype");
    
}

Answer (score 2):

Use < body onload="window.print()" > instead of calling  popup.print()

Answer (score 1):

You must create window print and add your font face and other css or js files in new window and then show them.

```
var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'width=842,height=595');
WinPrint.document.write('<html><head>');
WinPrint.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css">');
WinPrint.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Layout/font/persian-font.css">');
WinPrint.document.write('</head><body>');
WinPrint.document.write(document.getElementById('tagId').innerHtml);
WinPrint.document.write('</body></html>');
WinPrint.focus();
```